# Thunar not showing thumbnails in Openbox

Tags: openbox, thumbnails, thunar

I am using `openbox 3.5` and my file manager of choice is `Thunar` but the problem I am facing is thunar not showing thumbnails for `folder,video files` etc.

My Thunar:

[image]

You can see in the above image that thunar is not showing thumbnails for folders, files but it is showing for `pdf` and similar is the case for `video files` no thumbnails.

So, what is wrong here am I missing some basic thunar config files.

```
ranrag@ranrag:~$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
openbox
```

I looked into some forums and they mentioned that there is some dependency of `tumbler` with thunar but I have latest version of tumbler installed on my system.

PS: I already tried thunar preferences but still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I had to add the following line in my `~/.gtkrc-2.0`

```
gtk-icon-theme-name = "Tango"
```